# Google Search description: No information is available for this page

Tags: search, robots.txt, google-crawlers

When I search my website in google it shows as first place with my domain but the description is "*No information is available for this page.*" in order I corrected my robots.txt like this

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /bin/
```

and my home page already containing proper meta information like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="My website Search Engine description"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="some,keywords"/>
<title>My website Title</title>

<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
```

And in google webmaster, I resubmitted my sitemap.xml and Fetched my home URL, still no changes any suggestions? 
Or any other method to force re-crawl

Also, what is the default automatic crawl time when I change robot.txt or meta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed after waiting few hours nothing to do additionally, what I understand is the message "*No information is available for this page.*" is something new that google is showing in search while meta description not accessible causes by robots.txt

I already followed this doc https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7489871?hl=en&vid=0-298607595255-1511314327351 and corrected my robots.txt accordingly and waited few hours google bot automatically crawled and issue fixed.

Google bot Crawling time may vary depend on website traffic, some website may take one week.